# How to convert dimension dp to pixels?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-studio, imageview, picasso

While loading images using Picasso, the app become too slow due to high pixel size, Is there any option to reduce the pixel size without effecting the quality in android.

Answer (score 2):

For Piccaso You should use .

```
Picasso.with(context)
    .load(YOUR_IMAGE_PATH)
    .resize(600, 200) // resize your image to 600 x 200 ratio
    .onlyScaleDown() // the image will only be resized if it's bigger than 600x200 pixels.
    .into(IMAGEVIEW);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 Picasso.with(this)
 .load(Image_Path)
 .resize(imageView.getWidth(), imageView.getHeight())
 .into(imageView);;
```

Comment: Thank you for you reply.

Comment: But it effect the quality. And in addition also added scaledown to compress the dimension, but effect the quality

Answer (score 0):

**Use :**

```
Picasso  
.with(context)
.load(your_image_path)
.fit()
// call .centerInside() or .centerCrop() to avoid a stretched image
.into(imageViewFit);
```

**From Docs:**

> `fit()` is measuring the dimensions of the target `ImageView` and
>   internally uses `resize()` to reduce the image size to the dimensions
>   of the `ImageView.` There are two things to know about `fit()`. First,
>   calling `fit()` can delay the image request since Picasso will need to
>   wait until the size of the `ImageView` can be measured. Second, you
>   only can use `fit()` with an `ImageView` as the target.
>
> The advantage is that the image is at the lowest possible resolution,
>   without affecting its quality. A lower resolution means less data to
>   be hold in the cache. This can significantly reduce the impact of
>   images in the memory footprint of your app. In summary, if you prefer
>   a lower memory impact over a little faster loading times, `fit()` is a
>   great tool.

[learn more here](https://futurestud.io/tutorials/picasso-image-resizing-scaling-and-fit)

Comment: Thank you for you reply.